# imports via https not working in hardhat (solidity)

Tags: solidity, hardhat

Error HH406: Invalid import https://github.com/... from contracts/*MyContract*.sol. Hardhat doesn't support imports via https.

Trying to import forked contract from my github but https imports are not working in hardhat but works in remix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kevin mentioned, Hardhat currently does not support https imports in Solidity.

A good workaround is to use npm packages that contain the smart contracts you need. Ex. importing using the [@openzeppelin/contracts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openzeppelin/contracts) package.

Many established DApps will have their own npm package as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked with them [here](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/557); it seemes like they are currently not supporting this function yet.